# Get a inline style from a class in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, oop

I am using function for get the inline style.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style

I am trying like this.

```
public function __construct() {
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',  array( $this, 'wprm_enque_scripts' ) );
}
public function wprm_enque_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'inline-css' , plugins_url().'/wp-responsive-    menu/css/inline.css', array(), '1.0' );
  include( plugins_url().'/wp-responsive-menu/css/inline.php' );
  $custom_css = new WprmInlinecss;
  wp_add_inline_style( 'inline-css', $custom_css, array('jquery'), '1.0' );
}
```

In the WprmInlinecss class which is in the "inline.php" file, a variable $inlinecss is declared as member variable. In the "inline.php" i have written like this.

```
class WprmInlinecss {
    public $inlinecss = '';
    $options = get_option('wprmenu_options');
    if($options['enabled']) :

        $inlinecss .= '
                #wprmenu_bar {
                    background: '.$options["bar_bgd"].'
                }
    endif;

}
```

Now i want to get the $inlinecss variable in the "wprm_enque_scripts" function. How can i get the variable, so that i can use the variable as data in the wp_add_inline_style( $handle, $data ).

Comment: Your class is completely invalid...

Comment: How should it be valid ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
public function __construct() {
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',  array( $this, 'wprm_enque_scripts' ) );
}
public function wprm_enque_scripts() {
    $css = '#menu-wrapper{ min-height: '.get_option('menu_height').' }';
    $css .= '.menu-title{width: '.get_option('menu_title_width').'}'; 
    wp_add_inline_style( 'wprm-inline-stylesheet', $css );
}
```

Let me know this is working or not.

Comment: Yes, this is good. But i have lot of style css line. So i want have a different file and return the generated css by variable. So is that possible. Thanks for your reply.